# Automate messages on Discord (in background)

Tags: automation, background, discord

I was wondering if it was possible to automatically send messages without a script that moves the mouse, basically just having it run in the background without the script having to manually click on the textbox (that's the only thing I'm capable of doing atm).

Comment: Why without a script? I'd say that a script would perfectly do what you have in mind.

Comment: I meant like, without the script using my mouse and clicking on the textbox, I would like to have it running while I do other things and every couple of hours sending the message over to discord